# Calculate average of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I am new to SQL and I just can't figure out how to calculate the average of a certain value in two tables.

I have one table that is having all the information of the lakes in the world
and i have another tables including all the information of the seas in the world.

I want to calculate the average depth of the seas and lakes combined. I do know the following:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(depth) AS AvgDepthSeas
FROM
    sea
```

This will get me the average depth of the seas in the world.

```
SELECT 
    AVG(depth) AS AvgDepthLake
FROM
    lake
```

This will get me the average depth of all the lakes in the world.

I just can't figure out how to combine these two average numbers to calculate the average of the seas + lakes combined. I tried different thing like; Counting the amount of seas and lakes to see how much seas and lakes there are so I can combine the average numbers and divide them by the sum of seas+lakes/lakes.

I just know there must be an easier way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is where `union all` is really handy:

```
select avg(depth)
from ((select depth from sea) union all
      (select depth from lake)
     ) sl;
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem, I understand your solution but why is the 'sl;'  at the end? I know the code won't work without it I just dont realy understand why  'sl;' is needed there

Comment: That's just how the syntax goes - if you have a subquery in MySQL you have to give it an alias, even if you never reference the alias.

Answer (score 0):

@CodeBeginner12 , your longer attempt would have been something like:

```
select (sum(s.depth)+sum(l.depth))/(count(s.name)+count(l.name))
from seas s, lakes l
```

Gordon's solution is clearer and more practical.